# R - bulk import of csv with special characters ( ` ) on the file's name

Tags: r, import, bulk

Is there an extension to this code that allows the import of files with " ` " on their file' name?

dat  <- dir_ls(regexp = "*.csv") %>%
map_df(read_csv2 ,
col_types = cols(.default=col_character() )
)

Thanks again!

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having with such files? Are you getting an error or something when you use this code? Does the `dir_ls(regexp = "*.csv")` return the file names properly?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. Yes, I do... R simply doesn't recognize those files. Error: 'rf xxx³xxx.csv' does not exist in current working directory ('C:/Users/xxxxxxxxxx).